# What is the theoretical-terminological difference between M.2, SATA, PCIe?

Tags: sata, pci-express, ahci, m.2

SATA : is a *bus interface*
PCIe : is a *bus interface*
M.2 : is a *physical connector*

If that's the case, how could something be both `SATA` and `PCIe` at the same time?

Also, `U.2`, `SATA` and `SATAe` are all *physical connectors*.
Is `SATA` both *physical connector* and *bus interface*?

As I know, `ATA` uses `IDE` *protocol*.
`SATA` uses `AHCI` *protocol*.
`PCIe gen4` uses `NVMe` *protocol*.
And something cannot be `IDE`, `AHCI`, and `NVMe` at the same time.
But how could something use different `bus interfaces` at once?

Comment: [Loosely related answer to a different question](https://superuser.com/a/1619542/194694).

Comment: @gronostaj, It is related but it's more retailed toward the SSD part. However I'm more concerned about the second answer which says `"PCI-e slots don't exist in laptops ... M.2 slot into which you place a NVMe or SATA SSD."` isn't that just wrong? NVMe SSD is infact uses PCIe interface right?

Comment: PCIe port and PCIe interface are related, but completely separate things. PCIe ports use the PCIe interface, but are not available in laptops due to their form factor. M.2 ports can provide PCIe interface in some key configurations and are available both in laptops and desktops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, as you say, m.2 *is a connector*, not a protocol.

The m.2 connector supports a different set of pins depending on what protocol you want to use it for.  A connector can have both PCIe, SATA and USB wired up to it depending on what it is to be used for.

From [Wikipedia: M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) the M.2 connector can have different notches and pins wired up for different uses:

> [image]

| Key ID | Notched pins | Provided interfaces |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 8–15 | 2× PCIe ×1, USB 2.0, I2C and DP ×4 |
| B | 12–19 | PCIe ×2, SATA, USB 2.0 and 3.0, audio, UIM, HSIC, SSIC, I2C and SMBus |
| E | 24–31 | 2× PCIe ×1, USB 2.0, I2C, SDIO, UART, PCM and CNVi |
| M | 59–66 | PCIe ×4, SATA and SMBus |

Comment: 1) Does that mean [when someone says](https://youtu.be/ItMY3WHHowQ?t=184) `"M.2 uses 4 PCIe lanes"` he means when it configured to provide the PCIe with NVMe. But when speaking of an `M.2 SATA SSD` in this case, it doesn't use that said 4 lanes?

Comment: @RooTenshi Yes. an M.2 device can be either nVME (using PCIe), or it can have a standard SATA signal present on the connector. Many motherboards present both sets of signals at the M.2 connector and see what the device plugged in supports, while some specifically state PCIe or SATA so you know which version M.2 device you need to buy. The connector doesn't really care what you are plugging in as it has wires for pretty much everything, but your motherboard may only support particular devices on particular sockets.

Comment: 2) M.2 SATA SSD = (connector M.2 / Interface SATA / Protocol AHCI)  M.2 PCIe SSD = (connector M.2 / Interface PCIe / Protocol NVMe) 2.5" SATA SSD = (connector ??SATA?? / Interface SATA / Protocol AHCI)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. As for my 2nd comment, what I'm trying to say is, what connector does a 2.5in SSD use?

Comment: A 2.5" SATA drive uses a [SATA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Cables,_connectors,_and_ports) the protocol and the connector name being essentially same. You kind of have to guess by context as to whether SATA is referring to the protocol or connector or both. You can have SATA over M.2 or SATA over SATA, with the latter simply being "SATA" . There are also many SATA connectors, power and data and combined and usually 2.5" drives have the combined type.

Comment: Ok great. Now I all my questions are answered. Thanks a lot :)